# Send a request for a resource to a user in another tenant?

Tags: office-365, outlook

I have two separate tenants, say tenant1 and tenant2.

How can I share a tenant1 calendar with users in tenant2 so those tenant2 users can request access to a resource (a room) and have it approved by a user in tenant1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable external sharing on your first tenant site and need to invite second tenant by email address.